# Xcode AVFoundation crop image

Tags: ios, avfoundation, crop

I want to create an `OCR` application which allows the user to chose the specific area on which to apply the processing.

As of now, i am able to capture the entire image using the `AVFoundation` however, my current target is to use an overlay of some dimensions and capture the image inside that, So rather than the entire image being captured, I want the image only inside the overlay to be captured and used.

Answer (score 0):

```
+ (UIImage *)imageByCropping:(UIImage *)imageToCrop toRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([imageToCrop CGImage], rect);

    UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    return croppedImage;
}
```

Comment: Dada, Dhanyovad, apan Code khub bhalo kintu samsya is that I do not know exactly what dimensions of the rectange I should use, My aim is to use basically use the same dimension as specified during the overlay, kono sahaya?